# ! LaTeX Error: \mathbb allowed only in math mode

Tags: math-mode

Hi I got an error with following code：

```
$F(X) = \mathbf{1}_{(c,\infty)} := 
\begin{cases}
1 & if\ x \in [c,\infty) \\
0 & if\ x \not \in [c, \infty)
\end{cases} $
```

The error says:

```
! LaTeX Error: \mathbf allowed only in math mode.

 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

 l.282     \$F(X) = \mathbf{1}
                         \_\{(c,\infty)\} :=
? 
! Emergency stop.
...                                              

l.282     \$F(X) = \mathbf{1}
                         \_\{(c,\infty)\} :=
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!   
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: your error message clearly shows that you have `\$F` not `$F` at the start, so the error message was not generated by the code you posted.

Comment: There's something fishy here: you seem to be typing `\$F(X)=\mathbf(1}\_\{(c,\infty)\}` which should be `$F(X)=\mathbf{1}_{(c,\infty)}`. Remove the wrong backslashes.